# How to measure received signal strength, using DIY circuit

Tags: diy, rssi

I use 2.4GHz receivers for flying my RC planes via FPV. 
So i can get best reception i use multiple antennas on multiple video receivers.
I have a diversity controller that uses noise in the video signal to decide which receiver output i will be viewing. The problem with this arrangement is that the signal can switch from a less noisy receiver to a more noisy one and then back again.

There are many examples of diversity that use a RSSI output from the HF module to control the switching. However the brand i use doesnt have this output.

I was wondering if there is a way to add this functionality to my receivers.

Ideally i need an output between 0 and 5V.

Anyone else encountered this problem and come up with a good solution?

Comment: Could i use some sort of microvolt meter on the feed line?

Comment: Measuring the power in the feed line won't distinguish between in-band power and out-of-band power, and won't distinguish between signal and noise; by the time you fix those problems you've built most of a receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Something is inadequate in the way your diversity controller weighs "noise" if it changes in directions that increase subjective noise. You might construct a video signals comparator that applies a more appropriate test; that might be the strength of the sync pulse if you have peak-power sync pulses. Also it may reduce disruption to arrange gradual mix changes between video sources instead of cuts, though there would likely be some ghosting during the mixes, due to unequal propagation delays.

Comment: My diversity controller changes receiver when the picture becomes snowy or disrupted, all I'm able to adjust is the time that I put up with the static before it tries to switch